# Propriety and use of the phrase "commend to suspicion"

Tags: phrase-usage

I give up.
I've used the phrase "commend to suspicion" occasionally in legal writing and correspondence, as in "[existence of x] might commend to suspicion that [result y]."
My usage is specifically intended to sound antiquated based on my audience. It's not intended to evoke the meaning of suspicion in the investigatory/criminal sense, but rather an alternative to using "suggesting that" or "suggests that," which I already do.
Did I make this up? I can't find any use of it in Google.
Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of this, and it doesn't *look* like "natural English" to me. Besides which, in all the millions of publications indexed by Google Books, there's not a single instance of either ["commend to suspicion"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22commend+to+suspicion%22) or ["commended to suspicion"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22commended+to+suspicion%22). Unless you've got some pretty convincing counter-evidence that it might (or a sound argument as to why it *should*) be valid, I think this is Off Topic (answerable using common resources).

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commend) has the related sense of 'commend': << to recommend as worthy of confidence or notice
 • _Your proposal has much to commend it_. >> so 'highlight as important' is licensed. However, the 'to mention with approbation' sense exerts such a pull that 'commend to suspicion' sounds more than faintly ludicrous, certainly rarefied.

Comment: @FF Isn't 'answerable using common resources' sacrilegious now for all reference works except dictionaries? I do hope not.

Comment: Is this a usage you had seen somewhere, and were mimicking?

Comment: All - it's from the screenplay for "Lincoln" the 2012 film, and in it, Daniel Day Lewis in the titular role says "recommend to suspicion". That phrase, too, is rare. So apparently, I made up "commend to suspicion" by misquoting another phrase that's essentially made up.

Comment: That is an incorrect use of the verb commend. But first you say you have used it and then you say  want to sound antiquated. How very odd. And re MW, I don't think that suspicion can be commended to. You usage does not have much to commend it. That's the meaning...

Comment: You are free to deliberately use transparent understatement: We are not amused. Can I get back to you on that? I wish I could give you a positive reference for Ann beyond her punctuality. I suspect you may find it suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

To commend x to, in this sense, is often a reflexive. In this use - according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commends%20itself%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - it was relatively common in formal/high register in the early to late 19th century.

"[*The* existence of *a gun*] might commend *itself* to *the/your* suspicion that *[the accused intended murder]*."

That said, *in commending [itself] to X,* X was usually (usually does not mean "always") a person or people, or at least sentient.

Some examples:

> Addresses and Messages to the General Court, Proclamations,
> Massachusetts. Governor · 1878 ... commends itself to the heads of
> departments by relieving them from the importunities of personal and
> political friends ; it commends itself to the worthy applicants by
> treating them impartially
>
> The Task of Social Hygiene - Page 16 Havelock Ellis · 2019 ...
> commends itself to our Salmonidian sciolists.
>
> The Massachusetts Teacher: A Journal of School and Home 1848 ...
> commends itself to the patriot.
>
> Message of W. F. Packer, Governor of Pennsylvania - Page 10 William
> Fisher PACKER · 1860 ... commends itself to the favorable
> consideration of the Legislature .
>
> Ward's evangelical [afterw.] The Evangelical almanac - Page 60 1865
> ... commends itself to the rational understanding as faithful,
> "reliable," " believable," to be confided in as truth.

However, as a literary construction, it sounds authentic enough especially  if used consistently by one character.

Comment: No results found for "commend itself to the suspicion". No results found for "commend itself to your suspicion".[Google]

Comment: Thanks to Greybeard for the deep dive.